# Is it possible to save an object to disk as SceneKit SCN file created in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am creating some geometries in SceneKit with

```
SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, normalSource], elements: [element])
```

But I do not want save huge number of **sources** and **elements** to disk and
recreate them every time app started.

Is there a way to save created objects as SCN files to the disk in an iOS application.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to put objects (for instance a `SCNGeometry` instance) in a scene and then call [`-[SCNScene writeToURL:options:delegate:progressHandler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-writetourl) to save it on the disk.

Alternatively, most SceneKit classes conform to the [`NSSecureCoding` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding) which means they can be archived individually (without a scene).

For instance you can call `+[NSKeyedArchiver  archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:]` with the `SCNGeometry` instance as the root object and you'll obtain a `NSData` onto which you can call `-writeToURL:options:error:`.

In fact this is what the `-[SCNScene writeToURL:options:delegate:progressHandler:]` method does internally, with the scene as the root object.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is working;

First you save scene with objects you want to save as **.scn** file

```
 func saveScene(){
    let sceneToSave = scnView.scene
    let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let url = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent( "test.scn")
    scene2!.write(to: url, options: nil, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)
}
```

To get objects you saved;

```
    func loadObject(){
      let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
      let url = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent( "test.scn")
      var testGeometry = try! SCNScene(url: url, options: nil).rootNode.childNode(withName: "testGeometry", recursively: true)?.geometry
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on demand resources could be a solution to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/520-on-demand-resources-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: That could be a solution for some applications but I still need to know how to save objects.

Comment: Do you specifically need them on the disk?

Comment: Yes I need objects in iPhone.

Comment: Maybe this would do? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write